# How to rotate square following mouse by mouse movement angle?

Tags: javascript

I have square that follows my cursor.
Its border top is red to see if the rotation is right.
I'm trying to rotate it depending on mouse movement angle. Like if mouse goes 45deg top right then square must rotate by 45deg.
The problem is that when I move my mouse slowly the square starts to rotate like crazy. But if I move my mouse fast enough square rotates pretty smooth.

Actually it's just a part of my task that I'm trying to accomplish. My whole task is to make custom circle cursor that stretches when mouse moving. The idea I'm trying to implement:
rotate circle by mouse movement angle and then just scaleX it to make stretching effect. But I cannot do it because of problem I described above. I need my follower to rotate smoothly when mouse speed is slow.

```js
class Cursor {
    constructor() {
        this.prevX = null;
        this.prevY = null;
        this.curX = null;
        this.curY = null;
        this.angle = null;

        this.container = document.querySelector(".cursor");
        this.follower = this.container.querySelector(".cursor-follower");

        document.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
            this.curX = event.clientX;
            this.curY = event.clientY;
        });

        this.position();
    }


    position(timestamp) {
        this.follower.style.top = `${this.curY}px`;
        this.follower.style.left = `${this.curX}px`;


        this.angle = Math.atan2(this.curY - this.prevY, this.curX - this.prevX) * 180/Math.PI;
        console.log(this.angle + 90);

        this.follower.style.transform = `rotateZ(${this.angle + 90}deg)`;

        this.prevX = this.curX;
        this.prevY = this.curY;

        requestAnimationFrame(this.position.bind(this));
    }
}


        const cursor = new Cursor();
```

```css
.cursor-follower {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;

    pointer-events: none;
    user-select: none;

    width: 76px;
    height: 76px;
    margin: -38px;
    border: 1.5px solid #000;

    border-top: 1.5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor">
  <div class="cursor-follower"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try not to default to 90 deg? Also, only animate when the cursor moves?

Comment: I'm adding 90degs to atan2 result because it's output doesn't correspond to what I'd pass to rotate manually. Example: if I move cursor to top right (45deg in rotate function) atan2 returns me -45. And I'm adding 90 to make it 45 and then pass to rotate(). You can remove +90 yourself and see that it isn't the problem.

Comment: It's not about adding 90deg. 1) Moving in a straight line will make the angle default to 90 degrees. 2) Remove your requestAnimationFrame, because that one also defaults to 90deg. Can't help you more, because I can't figure out a solution to #1.

Comment: When moving mouse slowly, `mousemove` fires so fast, that the mouse has time to move only a pixel or two, and this will mess the angle between the prevous position and the current position (ex. 1px down and 1px right = 45deg). You've to calculate the cursor moving direction related to the center of the window.

Comment: When moving mouse slowly, mousemove fires so fast <= slow motion - small number of events are fired. In this case requestAnimationFrame is used - hence "fires so fast". Can't calc angle based on the center of the screen as (AFAIK) the idea is rotate the square based on current direction of mouse. A small improvement might be achieve if an average angle is calculated for a "small area of motion"

Comment: How can I calculate average angle then? Is this the best solution for my issue?

Comment: average angle => store last 3 points or so and calculate angles like a1 = α(curr, L1), a2 = α(curr, L2), a3 = α(curr, L3), than a = a1 * w1 + a2 *w2 + a3*w3 where (w1 + w2 w3 = 1) and (w1 > w2 > w3). The weight factors w1, w2, w3 are empirical, you should find some nice values for them like (w1 = 0.5, w2 = 0.35, w3 = 0.15). Other approach is to construct a curve through a few points and use interpolation and find a tangent (this might be too much). As long as only two points are used your animation won't be smooth.

Comment: Also, you need to handle +/-PI/2 case as there atan2 is going "crazy" commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Arctangent2.svg. It might be overkill but often en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation helps to avoid atan issue even for a such simple case as yours. How exactly don't know atm (haven't been involved in video-game industry for ages)

Comment: @Dragan The frequence of the the fired mousemove events is somewhat constant, it doesn't depend on the speed of the move. Also, you can calculate the mouse direction based on the center of the window, but I've to admit it's not very practical in this case.

Comment: Is [this what you actually need](https://jsfiddle.net/vmwoxgz6/)?

Comment: It is, but your implementation seems quite rude, I'll watch your code later

Comment: Rude ..? Do you mean the code is somehow rude, or the animation is not smooth enough?

Comment: Yes, I meant that it is not smooth. I'm not native speaker, sorry

Comment: It's all in your hand, the algorithm itself is almost as smooth as you can get. Take a look [this other fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6g87fmty/1/). It changes the cursor (after 10 secs) from quite smooth to a real quick silver cursor, which senses the smallest changes in the mouse moving. You can play with the parameters (at the beginning of the class) to adjust the cursor behavior. You can also check the automove by switching 0 to 1 in the last `if` condition at the end of the code (switch 1 to 0 in the previous `if`).

Comment: I'm currently working on another problem of mine. As soon as possible I'll take a look at your code. If what you're saying is true maybe you leave your code below in this thread and I'll mark your answer as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the cursor tangent smoothly isn't as simple as it first feels. In modern browsers mousemove event fires nearby at the frame rate (typically 60 FPS). When the mouse is moving slowly, the cursor moves only a pixel or two between the events. When calculating the angle, vertical + horizontal move of 1px resolves to 45deg. Then there's another problem, the event firing rate is not consistent, during the mouse is moving, event firing rate can drop to 30 FPS or even to 24 FPS, which actually helps to get more accurate angle, but makes the scale calculations heavily inaccurate (your real task seems to need scale calculations too).

One solution is to use [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to make the animation smoother. However, adding a transition makes the angle calculations much more complex, because the jumps between negative and positive angles [Math.atan2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2) returns when crossing PI will become visible when using transition.

Here's a sample code of how to use transition to make the cursor follower smoother.

```js
class Follower {
  // Default options
  threshold = 4;
  smoothness = 10;
  stretchRate = 100;
  stretchMax = 100;
  stretchSlow = 100;
  baseAngle = Math.PI / 2;
  // Class initialization
  initialized = false;
  // Listens mousemove event
  static moveCursor (e) {
    if (Follower.active) {
      Follower.prototype.crsrMove.call(Follower.active, e);
    }
  }
  static active = null;
  // Adds/removes mousemove listener
  static init () {
    if (this.initialized) {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.moveCursor);
      if (this.active) {
        this.active.cursor.classList.add('hidden');
      }
    } else {
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.moveCursor);
    }
    this.initialized = !this.initialized;
  }
  // Base values of instances
  x = -1000;
  y = -1000;
  angle = 0;
  restoreTimer = -1;
  stamp = 0;
  speed = [0];
  // Prototype properties
  constructor (selector) {
    this.cursor = document.querySelector(selector);
    this.restore = this.restore.bind(this);
  }
  // Activates a new cursor
  activate (options = {}) {
    // Remove the old cursor
    if (Follower.active) {
      Follower.active.cursor.classList.add('hidden');
      Follower.active.cursor.classList.remove('cursor', 'transitioned');
    }
    // Set the new cursor
    Object.assign(this, options);
    this.setCss = this.cursor.style.setProperty.bind(this.cursor.style);
    this.cursor.classList.remove('hidden');
    this.cHW = this.cursor.offsetWidth / 2;
    this.cHH = this.cursor.offsetHeight / 2;
    this.setCss('--smoothness', this.smoothness / 100 + 's');
    this.cursor.classList.add('cursor');
    setTimeout(() => this.cursor.classList.add('transitioned'), 0); // Snap to the current angle
    this.crsrMove({
      clientX: this.x,
      clientY: this.y
    });
    Follower.active = this;
    return this;
  }
  // Moves the cursor with effects
  crsrMove (e) {
    clearTimeout(this.restoreTimer); // Cancel reset timer
    const PI = Math.PI,
      pi = PI / 2,
      x = e.clientX,
      y = e.clientY,
      dX = x - this.x,
      dY = y - this.y,
      dist = Math.hypot(dX, dY);
    let rad = this.angle + this.baseAngle,
      dTime = e.timeStamp - this.stamp,
      len = this.speed.length,
      sSum = this.speed.reduce((a, s) => a += s),
      speed = dTime
        ? ((1000 / dTime) * dist + sSum) / len
        : this.speed[len - 1], // Old speed when dTime = 0
      scale = Math.min(
        this.stretchMax / 100,
        Math.max(speed / (500 - this.stretchRate || 1),
          this.stretchSlow / 100
        )
      );
    // Update base values and rotation angle
    if (isNaN(dTime)) {
      scale = this.scale;
    } // Prevents a snap of a new cursor
    if (len > 5) {
      this.speed.length = 1;
    }
    // Update angle only when mouse has moved enough from the previous update
    if (dist > this.threshold) {
      let angle = Math.atan2(dY, dX),
        dAngle = angle - this.angle,
        adAngle = Math.abs(dAngle),
        cw = 0;
      // Smoothen small angles
      if (adAngle < PI / 90) {
        angle += dAngle * 0.5;
      }
      // Crossing ±PI angles
      if (adAngle >= 3 * pi) {
        cw = -Math.sign(dAngle) * Math.sign(dX); // Rotation direction: -1 = CW, 1 = CCW
        angle += cw * 2 * PI - dAngle; // Restores the current position with negated angle
        // Update transform matrix without transition & rendering
        this.cursor.classList.remove('transitioned');
        this.setCss('--angle', `${angle + this.baseAngle}rad`);
        this.cursor.offsetWidth; // Matrix isn't updated without layout recalculation
        this.cursor.classList.add('transitioned');
        adAngle = 0; // The angle was handled, prevent further adjusts
      }
      // Orthogonal mouse turns
      if (adAngle >= pi && adAngle < 3 * pi) {
        this.cursor.classList.remove('transitioned');
        setTimeout(() => this.cursor.classList.add('transitioned'), 0);
      }
      rad = angle + this.baseAngle;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.angle = angle;
    }
    this.scale = scale;
    this.stamp = e.timeStamp;
    this.speed.push(speed);
    // Transform the cursor
    this.setCss('--angle', `${rad}rad`);
    this.setCss('--scale', `${scale}`);
    this.setCss('--tleft', `${x - this.cHW}px`);
    this.setCss('--ttop', `${y - this.cHH}px`);
    // Reset the cursor when mouse stops
    this.restoreTimer = setTimeout(this.restore, this.smoothness + 100, x, y);
  }
  // Returns the position parameters of the cursor
  position () {
    const {x, y, angle, scale, speed} = this;
    return {x, y, angle, scale, speed};
  }
  // Restores the cursor
  restore (x, y) {
    this.state = 0;
    this.setCss('--scale', 1);
    this.scale = 1;
    this.speed = [0];
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
Follower.init();

const crsr = new Follower('.crsr').activate();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.crsr {
  width: 76px;
  height: 76px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.cursor {
  position: fixed;
  cursor: default;
  user-select: none;
  left: var(--tleft);
  top: var(--ttop);
  transform: rotate(var(--angle)) scaleY(var(--scale));
}

.transitioned {
  transition: transform var(--smoothness) linear;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="crsr hidden">A</div>
```

The basic idea of the code is to wait until the mouse has moved enough pixels (`threshold`) to calculate the angle. The "mad circle" effect is tackled by setting the angle to the same position, but at the negated angle when crossing PI. This change is made invisibly between the renderings.

CSS variables are used for the actual values in `transform`, this allows to change a single parameter of the transform functions at the time, you don't have to rewrite the entire rule. `setCss` method is just syntactic sugar, it makes the code a little bit shorter.

The current parameters are showing a rectangle follower as it is in your question. Setting ex. `stretchMax = 300` and `stretchSlow = 125` and adding 50% border radius to CSS might be near to what you finally need. `stretchRate` defines the stretch related to the speed of the mouse. If the slow motion is still not smooth enough for your purposes, you can create a better algorithm to `// Smoothen small angles` section (in `crsrMove` method). You can play with the parameters at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c69gfhzy/).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
class Cursor {
    constructor() {
        this.prevX = null;
        this.prevY = null;
        this.curX = null;
        this.curY = null;
        this.angle = null;

        this.container = document.querySelector(".cursor");
        this.follower = this.container.querySelector(".cursor-follower");

        document.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
            this.curX = event.clientX;
            this.curY = event.clientY;
        });

        this.position();
    }


    position(timestamp) {
        this.follower.style.top = `${this.curY}px`;
        this.follower.style.left = `${this.curX}px`;


        if (this.curY !== this.prevY && this.curX !== this.prevX) {
        this.angle = Math.atan2(this.curY - this.prevY, this.curX - this.prevX) * 180/Math.PI;
        }
        console.log(this.angle + 90);

        this.follower.style.transform = `rotateZ(${this.angle + 90}deg)`;

        this.prevX = this.curX;
        this.prevY = this.curY;

        requestAnimationFrame(this.position.bind(this));
    }
}


        const cursor = new Cursor();
```